# storing access_token in satellizer , Oauth2 password grant

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, satellizer, laravel-passport

I'm using laravel passport Oauth2 password grant mechanism to authenticate my users. i'm simply taking there email and password and my server is returning,

`grant_type
access_token
refresh_token
expires`
 
everything is working great but i'm using `sahat/satellizer` library on my frontend(angular) so it's not storing my access_token in local storage so it can make authorization request and access data from the servee.

How can i make satellizer to store that token on my frontend ?

Comment: Are you asking how to save/store it to `localstorage` or how to use it without saving it to `localstorage` ?

Comment: how to configure it on satellizer so satellizer can store it on fronted and send in header with every request.